# Conditional return of values from other sheets in workbook if condition is true

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a summary page that would pull a row of values from other sheets in the workbook if a particular value is put in A2, A3 and so on on the summary page. 
I.e.
Summary A2="last name" then summary B2:M2 = sheet2 B2:M2
I've already named the ranges and the sheets. 
What's the best function to use to do this and how?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Google anything?

Comment: No need for sarcasm here.

Comment: Hi @oxana, No sarcasm intended and I apologize for coming across as such. Just this is a standard response when reviewing new posts. Next time, please include what you've tried so far :)